# Bad Display PHPMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Our PHPMYADMIN is displayed wrongly on our Centos server
We miss icons and text are displayed twice

[image]

Comment: have you refresh the page

Comment: yes but seems to be a pb because on our server we have multiple VM and only 2 have this problem

Comment: Have you tried with setting up Zoom settings to default of your webbrowser?

Comment: I'm sorry but my pb is not a display issue on my browser None have this issue. Only 2 and the problem seems to come from icon displayed and has it's not displayed we have text wihch replace it

Comment: it seems to me a style issue missing icons files something like this

Comment: Ok The pb is fixed